# Multer not populating req.files while using postman

Tags: node.js, postman, multer

I am working a on restful api that will read excel sheet and return data in the sheet in json format.but while uploading file(.xls) from postman and sending the request to api. the api gets crashed.

Below is my code :

from app.js

```
var app= express();
var upload = multer({

                    fileFilter : function(req, file, callback) {
                        if (['xls', 'xlsx'].indexOf(file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length-1]) === -1) {
                            return callback(new Error('Wrong extension type'));
                        }
                        callback(null, true);
                    }
                }).single('file');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var routes = require("./routes/routes.js")(app,upload);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

routes.js :

```
app.post('/uploadxl', function(req, res) {
  console.log("upload file");
      var exceltojson = require("xls-to-json-lc");
        upload(req,res,function(err){
          console.log("e");
            if(err){
                 res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                 return;
            }
            /** Multer gives us file info in req.file object */
            if(!req.file){
                res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:"No file passed"});
                return;
            }
            //start convert process
            /** Check the extension of the incoming file and
             *  use the appropriate module
             */
            if(req.file.originalname.split('.')[req.file.originalname.split('.').length-1] === 'xlsx'){
                exceltojson = xlsxtojson;
            } else {
                exceltojson = xlstojson;
            }
          var   node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
  node_xj({
    input: req.file.path,  // input xls
    output: "output.json", // output json
    sheet: "a"  // specific sheetname
  }, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("error");
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("--------result----");
      res.json(result);
    }
  });


        });
    });

}
```

I get this error on my windows command prompt :

upload file
e
You miss a input file

which clearly means it is entering the error function of multer.

[image]

Comment: Could You just try x-www-form-encoded format ?

Comment: i don't get a option to upload the file, already tried  the same

Answer (score 4):

Your problem seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746727/upload-file-on-express-js-app) question.

If you are using Postman, you can try removing the Header: "Content-type": "multipart/form-data".

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , but still getting the same result

Comment: Yes you want to write directive to get a file, here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/34205893/7862193

Comment: I  am trying to figure out if there is a issue with code(nodejs), this question is not about angularjs

Comment: Tried your code in my local system, haven't had any issues. Check my gist  
 https://gist.github.com/softmantk/4a6891e2fc7a2f1dd671be608c7f6482

Comment: Yes. Tried in both postman and advance rest client and working fine

Comment: I don't know your app's scope. Look at my code. I have modified your code to get the req.file in the response.

Comment: thanks, but m still  getting the same o/p,dont know whats the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162210/discussion-between-nikhil-c-m-and-rajeev-akotkar).